# What does "into the path" mean in football (soccer)?

Tags: meaning

What does "into the path" mean in football (soccer)?

> 30 minSHOT! There is a really good understanding between Lingard and Lukaku, who turns the ball **into the path of** his teammate who skips by a couple of Swansea defenders on his way across the box but then slices his shot wide. The midfielder must have left his shooting boots in Amsterdam.

Comment: I can see nothing difficult about that section. Just one of the normal meanings of "path"

Comment: Does it mean "way"?

Comment: Yes, it means "into the direction that his teammate is going".  It isn't specific to football/soccer.

Answer (score 1):

"*The path of the teammate*" is the imaginary line that the teammate is travelling along.

"*(to) turn the ball into the path*" is to make the ball reach or cross that imaginary line.

In other words, Lukaku has sent the ball to exactly the right position for Lingard to receive it.  (The rest of the quote suggests that although Lukaku did this perfectly, Lingard failed to capitalise on the opportunity).